# Display Suite node field in layouts

Tags: theming, entities, display-suite

Well it might be a simple solution but I don't get it.

I have a field in my content type "field_color". I can get the value of that field in my page.html.twig with {{ node.field_color.value }}

It works really good.

With Display Suite I created several layouts, but how to I access the field value within the layout.

I already tried:

```
{{ node.field_color.value }}
{{ ds_content.field_color.value }}
{{ ds_content.field_ }}
{{ ds_content.0 }}
{{ ds_content.1 }}
{{ ds_content.3 }}
```

nothing works.

Drupal 8, DS 2.5 stables

In my layouts.yml

```
sw_default_text:
  label: 'Text 1col Collapse'
  category: 'my cat'
  class: '\Drupal\ds\Plugin\DsLayout'
  template: layouts/sw_default_text/sw-default-text
  regions:
    middle:
      label: Content
```

My sw-default-text.html.twig:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Template for a 1 column layout.
 *
#}
<div {{ attributes.setAttribute('id', settings.css_id).addClass('row shrink', 'sw-default-text', settings.css_classes) }}>
  <div class="small-12 columns">
    {{ content.middle }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is you are having an issue because you are trying to access this in a Display Suite template, rather than from a page template.

You can probably access it via `{{ ds_region.field_color.0 }}` in the ds-3col.html.twig file. Some notes:

1. Replace ds_region with the name of the ds_region you want - e.g. `middle`.
2. The `0` will mean it prints the first item in the array - if you only have one item, this should be enough
3. You will need to have the field in the region on your Manage Display page.
4. Once done, you can then print `{{ left|without('body') }}`.
5. Make sure to clear your cache

I hope this helps.

You could also try to `{{ dump }}` the variables and see what is available for you (or better still `{{ kint }}` if you have the devel module installed), that will help you drill down through the options to get the one you need.

Comment: Well thanks it show that the field is available under node {content} doesn't work within in the page.twig

It shows also that the field is available under "protected 'fieldDefinitions'" whatever that means.

Comment: `{{ content }} ` is available as a node variable in the node template. `{{ node }}` is available as a page variable in the page template. See the list of available variables at the comments at the top of page.html.twig and node.html.twig. Are you trying to access these via the DS UI or via a DS template?

Comment: Via DS template

Comment: What is the name of the template and can you post the relevant code from it for us? Also, what type of field are you trying to get the value of? List? Term reference?

Comment: A normal plain textfield. There is not much to see because it’s a DS layout. The child theme parent is Zurb Foundation for Drupal. I added both things in my first post @Pierre.Vriens

Comment: Can you try `{{ content.middle.field_color.value }}`?

Comment: No sorry doesn't work. That would be to simple ;)
I didn't want to use jQuery, but it's a workaround. Place the vaule somewhere hidden and use it from there.

Comment: I've installed DS now for you and played around with it. My answer is updated. Please accept this answer if it works for you. Thanks.